# Existing field of type array is not recognized by the mongodb operator "$in"

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do an aggregate query in mongodb but the "$in" operator says that the field I pass it is not recognized as an array.

here is my aggregate query.

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'isVisible': true, 
      'creatorId': new ObjectId('63ec13a4a2e93ccf1865218e')
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'subscriptioncontracts', 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              '$and': [
                {
                  '$eq': [
                    '$userId', new ObjectId('64b7f95c9927ad922db3acc9')
                  ]
                }, {
                  '$gte': [
                    '$endDate', new Date()
                  ]
                }, {
                  '$lt': [
                    '$startDate', new Date()
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ], 
      'as': 'subscriptioncontracts'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'subscriptions', 
      'localField': 'subscriptioncontracts.subscriptionId', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'subscriptioncontracts'
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'subscriptioncontractsIds': {
        '$map': {
          'input': '$subscriptioncontracts', 
          'as': 'contract', 
          'in': '$$contract.creatorId'
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      '$or': [
        {
          'isPremium': false
        }, {
          'isPremium': {
            '$exists': false
          }
        }, {
          '$and': [
            {
              'isPremium': true
            }, {
              'creatorId': {
                '$in':
                  '$subscriptioncontractsIds'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

la the important thing is this:

```
{
    '$match': {
      '$or': [
        {
          'isPremium': false
        }, {
          'isPremium': {
            '$exists': false
          }
        }, {
          '$and': [
            {
              'isPremium': true
            }, {
              'creatorId': {
                '$in':
                  '$subscriptioncontractsIds'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

the error I get is "$in needs an array".

and this is the field to be added before doing the last match operation

[screenshot of the result of the field "subscriptioncontractsIds".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXG8Q.png)

I have tried all the ways and I know that the query works correctly because when I hardcode the id that appears in the array the query works correctly.

```
{
    '$match': {
      '$or': [
        {
          'isPremium': false
        }, {
          'isPremium': {
            '$exists': false
          }
        }, {
          '$and': [
            {
              'isPremium': true
            }, {
              'creatorId': {
                '$in':
                  [ObjectId('63ec13a4a2e93ccf1865218e')]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: In aggregation pipeline, use `$in` in the format of `{ $in: [ <expression>, <array expression> ] }`. Ref: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/

Comment: @ray like? `'creatorId': {'$in':[ <expression>, <array expression> ]}`

Comment: @NelsonGallego should be `{$in: ['$creatorId', [ObjectId('63ec13a4a2e93ccf1865218e')] ]`. You can post sample json documents instead of screenshot if you want to see working example in playground

Comment: To get the 'aggregation `$in`' inside of `$match` it needs to be wrapped with `$expr`

Answer (score 2):

This answer echoes the comments.  I chose to make it a real answer because mixing up the `find` form of `$in` with the aggregation operator `$in` is a common mistake and it is worthwhile to have searchable answer.

In aggregation pipeline, use `$in` in the format of `{ $in: [ <expression>, <array expression> ] }`.   See [the docs](https://mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in) for more info.

```js
{
    '$match': {$expr: {
      '$or': [
        {'isPremium': false},
        {'isPremium': {'$exists': false}},
        {'$and': [
            {'isPremium': true},
            {$in: [ '$creatorId', '$subscriptioncontractsIds' ]}
            ]
        }
      ]
    }}
}
```

Comment: Especially since the 'find form of `$in`' is the default behavior that you get inside of a `$match` aggregation stage...